# earning money online by watching youtube videos online is it haram or halal

Tags: money

I work for a company called XYZ that operates based on a pyramid or networking business model, which is more akin to a Ponzi scheme. This company, like other Ponzi schemes, does not sell or purchase any products, nor does it require you to recruit others to earn. As a member of the company, we generate income by watching YouTube videos(obviously the content must be in compliance with Sharia law if it is not according to the law of Sharia I do not watch or promote those videos). We must watch and like the videos of different YouTubers, and for each like or view, we receive a certain amount of money.

After reading various online articles, I understand that pyramid schemes are considered haram in Islam due to the practice of earning commission from others' efforts. My question is whether my involvement in this company is halal, given that I do not invite others to join my network, thus breaking the pyramid scheme. I am only watching videos and promoting the content of the creators so that they can reach a larger audience, which is how the YouTube algorithm works.

Please advise me. While I am aware that pyramid schemes are haram, I am not involved in inviting or selling products.